# BIC/AIC Optimal Values

Tags: aic, bic

I was reading this paper (https://dms.umontreal.ca/~augusty/FHMV_paper.pdf) and noticed in their analysis (specifically Tables 2 and 3), the *highest* AIC and BIC values are highlighted and used as justification for that particular model being superior. I though the goal was minimization of the AIC and BIC, which suggests in this case that the models with more negative values would be a better fit. Could anyone explain to me if I’m missing something obvious here? Thanks!

Comment: Some packages, e.g. mclust, return $-BIC$ and call it $BIC$, so the model with the highest such $BIC$ is the best. This is indeed confusing, fortunately this is just an annoying convention. Although take a closer look at the definitions in the paper, and check what software the authors used.

Comment: @corey979: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: I agree with @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica This would make a good answer. One of you two should make it so.